# Regex to style usernames in a block of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What would the regular expression be to wrap all usernames in a span, given that they start with an at symbol?

```
var strA = '@A ipsum @B'; // Original Text
var strB = '<span>@A</span> ipsum <span>@B</span>'; // After Regex
```

Comment: An asterisk or an at? Your description and your example do not agree.

Comment: What are the valid characters in a user name?

Comment: This is to style a paragraph of text containing an occasional username.  I would like all of the `@Someone` and `@SomeoneElse`'s to have a different style, with a regex and jQuery to switch them out.  The usernames have already been validated to contain only alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with:

```
strB = strA.replace(/(@[^\s+])/g, '<span class="hilite">$1</span>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be something like this:

```
/(?:\W|^)(@(\w+))/
```

Catch group 1 contains your username with and catch group 2 without the `@`.

A bit clumsy, but as (last time I checked) Javascript's regex does not support lookbehinds, it's the cleanest way to do it, I'd say.

Comment: Better change that lookahead to a regular capturing subexpression.  Otherwise, when used in a `replace()`, the lookahead portion of the match will be removed.  Ie `"Thanx @Regexident"` becomes `"Thanx<span>@Regexident</span>"` with the space removed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `/(^|\s)(@\w+)\b/g`:

```
string.replace(/(^|\s)(@\w+)\b/g, "$1<span>$2</span>");
```

Depending on what characters are allowed in a user name, it may need some modification.

Comment: That would not match `...@foo...` (where `...` would be non-alphanumeric) but would match `...foo@bar...` and thus be pretty much the opposite of what arby wants to match, no?

Comment: @Regexident - Good catch.  I was wrong about how `\b` worked with `@`.  Updated my answer.

Comment: still invalid. Consider this common pre-native retweeting format: `RT "@foo: ..."` (as it's quite obvious arby's dealing with tweets, I'd say)